# Are sentences starting with "that" (conjunction) standard English

Tags: conjunctions, translation

In Dutch one could say things such as

Dat hij dat durft! 
*That* he that dares!

(An exclamation of astonishment)

Which would be roughly translated as: ***that*** he dares to do that. 
Is that initial *that* standard English? If not, how would a native English speaker translate that sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a common way of constructing expressions of astonishment and strong disagreement in most Germanic languages: using a subordinate clause and leaving out the main clause. Something like, “It shocks me [that…]” is then left unspoken, but pregnantly implied.

Google indicates that it works in German, too, though I’m not proficient enough myself to be quite certain (Afrikaans I tend to just ignore as being generally odd), and it certainly works in all the Scandinavian languages quite exactly as in Dutch: *at du tør!* (‘that you dare!’) or *at du ikke skammer dig!* (‘that you are not ashamed of yourself!’) in Danish should be almost directly intelligible to you.

However, as is often the case with these ‘pan-Germanic’ patterns and phenomena, English, in her insulation and Sinatricity<sup>1</sup>, has decided here that pan-Germanicisms are no good and got rid of it along the way—so the construction does not normally work in English, though there are still one or two remnants lying around (like Colin’s example, “That I should live to see this …” in the comment below, or something like, “That I never thought of this before …”). The semantic implication of the pan-Germanic pattern (that the thing mentioned not only astonishes, but also appals, you) is gone, though: only the element of unexpectedness is preserved.

A native English speaker would instead say, ***“How dare you?”*** and ***“You should be ashamed of yourself!”*** in the two cases given above. The subtle distinction the other Germanic languages are able to make between the two constructions cannot be expressed in English.

<sup>1</sup> By which I mean that like Frank Sinatra, English must always do everything *my way*.

Comment: Very nicely written answer. Thank you. In third person singular, would one say "How dares he?" / "How doe she dare?" It sounds rather archaic to my non-native ears.

Comment: There are literary examples with _that_ - I can't think of a specific one, but "That I should live to see ... " comes to mind - but I agree that this doesn't exist in the normal language.

Comment: No, it would be ***“How dare he?”***. Even though there is nothing following it so you can’t really tell, _dare_ acts as a modal verb here, which means it doesn’t take _-s_ in 3sg and can be followed by a plain infinitive without _to_ (like ‘he can/must/will/should/ought to’, etc.). Verbs like _dare_ and _need_ can be both full verbs and modal verbs: ‘He dares _to_ hit her!’ vs. ‘How dare he hit her!’ (with no _to_).

Comment: @ColinFine, good point, hadn’t thought of that one at all. Editing.

Comment: I really like "... is then left unspoken, but _pregnantly_ implied."